# groupby and then create a counter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "name": {0: "ABC", 1: "ABC", 2: "ABC", 3: "RED", 4: "RED", 5: "RED"},
            "d1": {
                0: pd.Timestamp("2020-04-02 00:00:00"),
                1: pd.Timestamp("2000-02-02 00:00:00"),
                2: pd.Timestamp("2021-01-02 00:00:00"),
                3: pd.Timestamp("1998-01-01 00:00:00"),
                4: pd.Timestamp("2020-03-02 00:00:00"),
                5: pd.Timestamp("2014-02-02 00:00:00"),
            },
            "d2": {
                0: pd.Timestamp("2021-03-02 00:00:00"),
                1: pd.Timestamp("2020-01-01 00:00:00"),
                2: pd.Timestamp("1923-02-02 00:00:00"),
                3: pd.Timestamp("2020-01-01 00:00:00"),
                4: pd.Timestamp("1995-02-02 00:00:00"),
                5: pd.Timestamp("2021-03-03 00:00:00"),
            },
        }
    )
```

I want to do a count following this logic:

1. groupby names
2. for each individual name, if the d1 date is larger than the rest within that name, count 1

for example, for name ABC, there are three dates, the return should be :

```
ABC  2 (2020>2000)
ABC  0 (2000 is larger than no one) 
ABC  3 (2021>2020>2000)
```

is there anyway I could do this count?

my current code looks like below but is not working:

```
new_df = df.sort_values(by = 'name')
for date in new_df['d1']:
   if date < new_df['d1']:
       count +=1
       return count
```

Comment: Why being larger than no one counts to `0` while being larger than one value counts to `2`? I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

`rank` is convenient for this.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('name')['d1'].transform('rank', ascending=True) - 1

df.loc[df['count'] > 0, 'count'] += 1

print(df)
name    d1  d2  count
0   ABC 2020-04-02  2021-03-02  2.0
1   ABC 2000-02-02  2020-01-01  0.0
2   ABC 2021-01-02  1923-02-02  3.0
3   RED 1998-01-01  2020-01-01  0.0
4   RED 2020-03-02  1995-02-02  3.0
5   RED 2014-02-02  2021-03-03  2.0
```